# how to use logparer for page stats

Tags: iis, logparser

Does anyone have a script for logparser that will output a graph for daily page visits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogParser "SELECT TOP 20 cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) AS Hits INTO MyChart.gif FROM
  GROUP BY cs-uri-stem ORDER BY Hits DESC"
 -chartType:Column3D -groupSize:1024x768